# What's the deal with the white man spectating the match set in 1200 AD, Alabama?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, echo-2024

In Season 1, Episode 2 of *Echo*, titled “Lowak”, we see a flashback to 1200 AD, Alabama, where Maya’s ancestor, Lowak, leads her team in a fierce game where the losing team would be “banished from [those] lands forever”.

Among the native spectators, there is an odd figure: a white man dressed in European-style clothing, complete with metal buckles. He also has a distinctive scarred and white eye, and some facial markings or tattoos.

[image: the white man described above]

This seems out-of-place for the pre-Columbian setting, since, if I'm not mistaken, it would be hundreds of years before European contact with Native Americans in this area.

The director of this episode, Sydney Freeland, has confirmed in an [interview](https://youtu.be/fJse5n5tnhc?t=185) that the scene was set in a “section of America pre-European contact”, and that the spectators were from various Native American tribes. But she has not explained who this man is or why he is there. (Relevant part starts at 3:05.)

What's the deal with his appearance? As far as I know, this was not addressed or referenced in the other episodes. Is he a reference to historical evidence of Europeans witnessing Native American sports in or around Alabama circa 1200 AD? Or is he a reference to events or characters from the comics or other Marvel media?

Comment: Allegedly, the norse (vikings) were visiting the north american continent in the 1100s so it's *possible* that they might have gotten inland as far as modern day Alabama but this seems unlikely. His dress seems too modern(ish) for that period.

Comment: Since this is science fiction it's entirely plausible to assert that Viking explorers or settlers made it as far as Alabama.

Comment: Could also be young Odin, what with scar and missing/ blind right eye?

Comment: Alabama is *much* further south (and west) than Newfoundland, so that would be a stretch.

Comment: *Odin* ... I like it! ☺

Comment: I believe in the Viking theory. While there's only been found a sttlement in New Foundland, the sagas suggest that they went at least as far south as Gulf of St. Lawrence. From there, river systems connect all the way down to Alabama (with a little overland haul, which the Vikings practiced going through Ukraine to the Black Sea. If, in an alternate history, Viking settlement flourished along the Great Lakes, an explorer could easily have found his way down south.

Comment: When watching this scene for the first time, I definitely thought that guy was a Viking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to *Echo* concept artist [Winona Nelson](https://www.instagram.com/winonanelsonart/), that man is indeed a Viking, as some have speculated. Unfortunately, they did not explain further as to how or why the Viking man was there.

[image: screenshot of Instagram post]

> Another Cahokia key illustration, this time focused more on the denizens, a wide mix of tribes and cultures represented. I loved seeing all the activity and commerce come to life! And he's not wearing the same costume but **the Viking we snuck in here got into a shot**!

- [Instagram post by @winonanelsonart](https://www.instagram.com/p/C2iExbUOoVG/) (emphasis mine)

Comment: Next question, does Odin count as a Viking?